# Enable text highlighting in VsVim

Tags: search, vim, highlight, vsvim

I really like text highlighting in Vim for searches and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd>. Is there anyway to enable it in VsVim on VS 2010 or VS 2012?

Comment: Maybe @JaredPar can help you on this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added a `.vsvimrc` file into my user home directory i.e. `C:\Users\joe.bloggs` that contains the following command:

```
 :set hlsearch
```

which is the regular Vim *highlight search* option.